# Fullscreen mode in processing

Tags: height, width, processing, fullscreen

I'm making a little game in Processing. But I don't know how to set the coordinates to be the same on every monitor type using fullscreen. Like in a big monitor the coordinates are different from a smaller monitor.

I tried to translate the center to the middle of the screen!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please, try to be more specific - show code snippets, etc. Otherwise, it will be not possible to answer you question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're using absolute coordinates, like this:

```java
void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){
 ellipse(250, 250, 400, 400); 
}
```

This code draws a large circle in the middle of the screen. The problem is, this code does not consider the size of the window at all. So if you make it fullscreen, the circle keeps the same size and location.

Instead, you can use the `width` and `height` variables to make your drawing scale with the window:

```java
void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){
 ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, width * .8, height * .8); 
}
```

Now the drawing will scale with the size of the window.

However, now you have a different problem: the drawing can get stretched out depending on the size of your monitor. You need to fix the **aspect ratio**. I'd recommend Googling that to see a ton of approaches, but for this simple example, you could just take the minimum of `width` and `height` and use that:

```java
void setup() {
  fullScreen();
}

void draw() {
  float minDimension = min(width, height);
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, minDimension * .8, minDimension * .8);
}
```

There are a ton of other ways to approach this. You could also look into using a `PGraphics` that's always the same size, and then scaling that depending on the screen size.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/using-variables) and [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-variables) are tutorials on using the `width` and `height` variables to scale your drawings.

Comment: Hi Kevin! I'm using fullscreen but in a 1920x1080 there are more pixels than in a 1600x900 and that will affect my program. I already searched a lot... TY